# Opentok web Mobile to PC orientation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opentok

I am trying to create an app with OpenTok. I'm using Opentok react (https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-react) but I'm also fine to do it from plain javascript if required.

The problem I'm facing is the image that the PC is subscribed to, which is coming from the mobile phone back camera, is always horizontal. I'm able to manually transform it using CSS to rotate it, but this would require the PC user manually clicking a button to do this.. I was hoping it could be done automatically..

I've tried listening to videoDimensionsChanged but it never seems to be called. Below is the code I am using with the    library

*below code is in react, but Im happy to use plain js also*

```
const subscriberEventHandlers = {
    videoDisabled: event => {
        console.log('Subscriber video disabled!'); //is called
    },
    videoEnabled: event => {
        console.log('Subscriber video enabled!'); //is called
    },
    videoDimensionsChanged: event => {
        console.log("video dimension changed", event); //never called
    }
};



 <Container>
                <div className={Styles.videoWrapper}>
                    <OTSession
                        apiKey={config.openTokApi}
                        sessionId={globalContext.session.response.session.id}
                        token={globalContext.session.response.session.token}
                        onConnect={() => console.log("OT connected")}>
                        <OTStreams>
                            <OTSubscriber eventHandlers={subscriberEventHandlers} />
                        </OTStreams>
                    </OTSession>
                </div>
            </Container>
```

Comment: Can you please check in your video captured orientation in android ( sender endpoint ) ? Change it to vertical or appropriate orientation in your android app and thus it will be changed in your viewer endpoint.

Comment: @michael Manik here from TokBox. Can you share which browser you're using? Is it iOS Safari or Chromium on Android?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Chromium from a Andriod One Phone. the thing is on a Pixel phone it does flip properly without any intervention.. the problem is my app needs to work on as many phones as possible

Comment: its resolved. ill add the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my Chrome browser was not rotating, once I allowed it to rotate, the image rotated correctly and events fired.